# несовершенный вид к "наскучить"?

Tags: грамматика

Мне все наскучило. Мне всегда все быстро **наскучивает**(?)

Подскажите общелитературный синоним.

Comment: Надоедает, приедается, перестаёт быть интересным?

Comment: вот "приедается", пожалуй, сойдет.

Comment: behemothus, почему пренебрегаете использованием буквы *Ё*? В данном случае она необходима, потому что *всё* (наскучило) и *всё* — это разные вещи.

Comment: Потому, что все (без ё) в данном случае невозможно по прочтению. Ё обязательна к употреблению в тех случаях, когда возможна двусмысленность, это касается и пары все/всё. А вообще - просто не задумывался.

Answer (score 3):

*Наскучивать* – в словаре Лопатина имеется такой глагол.

Comment: Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир. Том второй (1867-1869) Несколько раз балалайку настраивали и опять дребезжали те же  звуки, и **слушателям не наскучивало**, а только хотелось еще и еще слышать эту игру.  И. А. Гончаров. Обломов (1859)   **Если же Обломову наскучивало быть одному** и он чувствовал потребность выразиться, говорить, читать, рассуждать, проявить волнение, ― тут был всегда покорный и готовый слушатель и участник,  разделявший одинаково согласно и его молчание, и его разговор, и волнение, и образ мыслей, каков бы он ни был.

Comment: Ну Лопатин мне тут не аргумент. У него словарь толковый. Граф - тем более.

Comment: Зализняк ***наскучивает*** : http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-paradigm-term-36621.htm

Comment: "Ну Лопатин мне тут не аргумент. У него словарь толковый." ... "Русский орфографический словарь» — самый большой по объему из существующих орфографических словарей русского языка. Это академический словарь, отражающий русскую лексику в том её состоянии, которое сложилось к концу XX — началу XXI века. Словарные единицы даются в их нормативном написании с указанием ударений и необходимой грамматической информацией."

Comment: Не нравятся старорежимные граф с Гончаровым, пожалуйте из советских классиков :   Константин Ваншенкин. Писательский клуб (1998)  **Но часто ему это наскучивало**, хотелось выйти ― потолкаться в кулуарах, повидать приехавших из других городов, наконец, просто покурить. 
Евгений Носов. Усвятские шлемоносцы (1977)  Касьяну и самому **никогда не наскучивало** поглядывать в эти оконца...

Answer (score 1):

Составители словарей не могут, не в состоянии охватить всю словообразовательную парадигму русского языка. Поэтому, в частности, многие глагольные формы не указаны в справочных изданиях. Например, редкий глагол ***наскучаться*** есть только в словаре Ефремовой :

> НАСКУЧАТЬСЯ
>   наскучаться [наскучаться] сов. разг. Поскучать много, вдоволь.

Но писатели нет-нет, да и вплетут это словечко в ткань своего произведения :

> Виктор Астафьев. Царь-рыба (1974)
>   Берите Север, берите, если надо! **Мы тут намерзлись, наплакались, наскучались.**
>   Г. Е. Николаева. Битва в пути (1959)
>   «Разве объяснишь, **как мы с отцом наскучались**?
>   Г.И. Успенский. Кой про что (1885)
>   Они только что были у знакомых, где **вдоволь наскучались**, вдоволь наелись и выпили, и вот какая-то нелегкая занесла их опять в какую-то скверную клетку скучать, есть и пить.

То же самое касается глагола *наскучивать*. Редкоиспользуемая форма, однако она имеет все права на свое существование, что доказывают примеры из Нацкорпуса, орфографический словарь Лопатина и знаменитый труд Зализняка , см. ответ @Niemand и комментарии к нему. Синонимы к слову *наскучивать* имеются, я бы выбрал целый фразеологизм : **набивать оскомину**. Поищем подходящее словоупотребление :

> Ю. Н. Тынянов. Кюхля (1925)
>   В его высоте есть что-то двусмысленное. **Он набивает
>   оскомину** , как недозрелый плод. Всю жизнь писал о
>   любви, а любил безобразных женщин.